# Unable to tell if my Radix sort is working properly in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, radix-sort

I'm having problems getting my code to work. It's supposed to ask for the user to define the size of an array, and then for the radix and use that to sort the array. When I try to display the sorted array to check that it's sorted it out puts "[]". Below is my code.

```html
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Please enter the size of the array: ");
        
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numBits = input1.nextInt();
        
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter size of radix: ");
        int radixNum = input2.nextInt();
        getBits(radixNum);
        
        ArrayList<Integer> sortIt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        radSort(sortIt, radixNum, numBits);
        System.out.println(sortIt.toString());

    }

    private static int getBits(int radixNum) {
        double lognum = Math.log(10000);
        double logbase = Math.log(radixNum);
        int numBits = (int) Math.floor((lognum / logbase) + 1);
        System.out.println("Bits " + numBits);
        return numBits;
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the array in a radix sort where the radix is decided by the user
     *     
* @param sortIt
     * @param radixNum
     */
    private static ArrayList radSort(ArrayList<Integer> sortIt, int radixNum, int numBits) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> bucketStorage = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Integer> temp;
        temp = sortIt;
        int tempNumb;
        for (int i = 0; i < radixNum; i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> bucket = new ArrayList<>();
            bucketStorage.add(bucket);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < numBits; j++) {
            while (!temp.isEmpty()) {
                tempNumb = temp.remove(0);
                bucketStorage.get(getBitNumber(tempNumb, j, radixNum)).add(tempNumb);
            }
            for (int m = 0; m < bucketStorage.size(); m++) {
                for (int n = 0; n < bucketStorage.get(m).size(); n++) {
                    temp.add(bucketStorage.get(m).get(n));
                }
                bucketStorage.get(m).clear();
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    private static int getBitNumber(int a, int b, int R) {
        double expNum;
        int entry;
        expNum = Math.pow(R, b);
        entry = (int) Math.floor(a / expNum) % R;
        return entry;
    }
}
```

**strong text**

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: I've tried running it, but can't get the sorted array to display. We've  never really gone over debugging in netbeans.